# In iOS, is there any way for me to bypass a VPN for specific websites?

Tags: iphone, ios, network, vpn

I'm trying to set up a IKEv2 VPN on my iPhone that uses "connect on demand". However, there's a few websites where it's important for me to *not* use the VPN when connecting to them. Is there any way I can set up my phone to not use the VPN for those specific sites?

Basically, I don't want to have to go into Settings, manually turn off "connect on demand", disconnect from the VPN, do my work on the site, and then manually turn "connect on demand" back on again every single time I need to use one of these sites, which is frequently.

I'm open to using third party apps of some sort to accomplish this.

Comment: To confirm, you want to send ALL traffic over the VPN EXCEPT these certain sites?

Comment: Yes, preferably.